# Упростить генератор

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть экземпляр класса, который принимает несколько значений. Из них меняются только два - 'a',  'b'. Причём, 'a' меняется каждый раз, а 'b' меняется только дважды.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы список этих экземпляров генерировался на лету.
'a' - это координата. Значения убывают с шагом '-10'. То есть используется `range(640, 420, -10)`
'b' - это стейт. Значения бывают самое первое - 'PRESSED', потом следуют много 'MOVE', в конце 'RELEASED'.
Нужно сгенерировать список вида

```
[A(640, 'PRESSED'),
A(630, 'MOVE'),
A(620, 'MOVE'),
...
A(450, 'MOVE'),
A(440, 'MOVE'),
A(430, 'RELEASED')]
```

Простая арифметика даёт нам понять, что элементов будет 22.
На данный момент я делаю генератор списка координат, а дальше циклом с вложенным оператором if я создаю список этих экземпляров:

На данный момент я всё делаю так:

```
exmp = []
coordinates = [i for i in range(640, 420, -10)]
for coordinate in coordinates:
    if coordinates.index(coordinate) == 0:
        exmp.append(A(coordinate, 'PRESSED'))
    elif coordinates.index(coordinate) == 21:
        exmp.append(A(coordinate, 'RELEASED'))
    else:
        exmp.append(A(coordinate, 'MOVE'))
```

Но код страшно не нравится. Можно ли его как-то упростить? Необходимо получить этот вот список exmp каким-то более читаемым и простым способом и без привязки к индексам, как использовано в if-ах. Чтобы оно просто брало первый элемент, впихивало в него первую (само понимало, что координата первая) координату из генератора и ставило стейт 'PRESSED', потом вторую координату, ставило стейт 'MOVE', третью, и в самом конце брало последнюю (само понимало, что это последняя координата) координату и ставило стейт 'RELEASED'.

Comment: `exmp = [A(640, 'PRESSED')] + [A(i, 'MOVE') for i in range(630, 430, -10)] + [A(430, 'RELEASED')]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A = tuple # Demo

start = 640; stop = 430; step = -10
assert start > stop

qty = int((start - stop) / abs(step)) + 1

coors = range(start, stop - 1, step)
state = ['PRESSED'] + ['MOVE'] * (qty - 2) + ['RELEASED']

exmp = list(map(A, zip(coors, state)))

print(exmp)
```

Но можно запихать и в одну строчку, если занимаемся спортивным сокращением кода)

```
exmp = list(map(A, zip(range(640, 420, -10), ['PRESSED'] + ['MOVE'] * 20 + ['RELEASED'])))
```

Comment: в `assert` скобки не нужны

Answer (score 1):

Либо взять код из комментария EzikBro, либо можно так (смесь двух кодов):

```
exmp = []
coordinates = range(640, 420, -10)
exmp.append(A(coordinates[0], 'PRESSED'))
for coordinate in coordinates[1:-1]:
    exmp.append(A(coordinate, 'MOVE'))
exmp.append(A(coordinates[-1], 'RELEASED'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start = 640
stop  = 420
step  = -10

sequence = [
    ('PRESSED' if i == 0 else 'RELEASED' if x == stop - step else 'MOVED', x)
        for (i, x) in enumerate(range(start, stop, step))]
```

---

Как вариант, вместо нестабильного `x == stop - step`, которое сломается, если stop-start не кратно step, можно посчитать последний индекс: `i == (stop-start)//step-1`